# LottieView autoPlay prop doesn't work react native

Tags: react-native, animation, expo, lottie

I'm using AppIntroSlider with LottieAnimations and i have troubles with animation launching on IOS.

```
    <View style={styles.slide}>
      <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
      </View>

      {item.key > 1 && (
        <LottieView
          source={item.lottieAnimation}
          autoPlay={true}
          loop={true}
          speed={0.7}
        />
      )}

      <Image source={item.image} style={styles.image} />

      <Text style={styles.text}>{item.text}</Text>
    </View>
```

It shows only a frist frame and animation doesn't start.
"lottie-react-native": "^5.0.1"

Comment: Hey did you resolve it? I have similar issue

Comment: @Mateusz  unfortunately no